# Scala Marshalling/Unmarshalling

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

I'm trying to write a custom Marshaller for a very simple object, but it seems the scala runtime is not able to find it.

Following the spray template, I've defined the route as follows:

```
package com.example

import akka.actor.Actor
import spray.routing._
import spray.http._
import MediaTypes._
import com.example.dto.RecipeEntry
import com.example.dto.RecipeEntryJson._


trait RecipeManager extends HttpService {

  val myRoute =
    path("recipe") {
      post {
        decompressRequest() {
          entity(as[RecipeEntry]) { recipe =>
            complete(s"picture is $recipe.image")
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

and I've tried to define the Marshaller[RecipeEntry] as such:

```
package com.example.dto

import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
import spray.httpx.unmarshalling._
import spray.httpx.marshalling._
import spray.http._


case class RecipeEntry(originSite: String, image: String)

object RecipeEntryJson extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

    implicit val jsonMarshaller: Marshaller[RecipeEntry] = jsonFormat2(RecipeEntry.apply)
}
```

but I keep getting the following error:

> RecipeManager.scala:18: could not find implicit value for parameter um: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[com.example.dto.RecipeEntry]
>   [error]           entity(as[RecipeEntry]) { recipe =>

In fact, I'm running into the same problem as [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932234/spray-json-error-could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-um), however adding `import com.example.dto.RecipeEntryJson._` did not help

I must be missing some small detail (probably quite a few, as I'm very new to scala and spray), but I've tried a number of things but to no avail. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Your declaring it as  Marshaller[RecipeEntry] might be the issue. If I recall correctly the return type of jsonFormat[T] should be a RootFormat[T] which extends the relevant readers and writers. I believe you are essentially downcasting your type which is valid but not what is expected. Small note: this is a compile-time and not runtime issue.

Comment: It's related: If you define it as a `Marshaller` only you can write json responses but are not able to read json requests for which you need an `Unmarshaller`. The simplest solution is thus to replace the result type `Marshaller[RecipeEntry]` by `RootJsonFormat[RecipeEntry]` and move `import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._` to the routing file. This import will automatically provide both a `Marshaller` and an `Unmarshaller` if it is in scope.

Comment: I think that you may be missing another implicit that is required by the directive or the marshaller. If I'd have to bet I'd say you lack an `ExecutionContext` in scope, but I didn't try your code so I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses! And @jrudolph changing the type did work (I'd b happy to accept it as an answer). Appreciate it!