# Could not find implicit value for parameter um

Tags: scala, unmarshalling, implicit, akka-http, spray-json

I had an Main app with the following structure:

```
implicit val orgs: RootJsonFormat[GHOrg]                = jsonFormat3(GHOrg)
implicit val users: RootJsonFormat[GHUser]              = jsonFormat2(GHUser)
implicit val repos: RootJsonFormat[GHRepo]              = jsonFormat3(GHRepo)
case class GHUser(login: String, contributions: Option[Int] = None)
case class GHRepo(name: String, owner: GHUser, contributors_url: String)
case class GHOrg(name: String, repos_url: String, members_url: String)
```

At some point I do

```
Unmarshal(e).to[List[GHRepo]]
```

And everything works, however, I have been doing a little bit of code cleaning and I have moved the three case classes above to a different package, and now I am getting title's error. I have tried this suggestion ([spray-json error: could not find implicit value for parameter um](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932234/spray-json-error-could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-um)) but does not work.

Here is how the current code (Not compiling):

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.javadsl.model.StatusCodes
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshal
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import com.elbauldelprogramador.domain.{GHOrg, GHRepo, GHUser}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
import spray.json.RootJsonFormat

object Main extends App {

  implicit val system: ActorSystem                        = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer            = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher
  implicit val orgs: RootJsonFormat[GHOrg]                = jsonFormat3(GHOrg)
  implicit val users: RootJsonFormat[GHUser]              = jsonFormat2(GHUser)
  implicit val repos: RootJsonFormat[GHRepo]              = jsonFormat3(GHRepo)
// ....
Unmarshal(e).to[List[GHRepo]] // Error
// ....
}
```

Here is the full error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller[akka.http.scaladsl.model.ResponseEntity,List[com.elbauldelprogramador.domain.GHUser]]
>   [error]               val users = Unmarshal(e).to[List[GHUser]]
>   [error]                                          ^

Comment: What is error you got? Try don't use akka to localize the error, e.g., use `jsonBody.parseJson.convertTo[List[GHRepo]]`.

Comment: I don't have a jsonBody, I have a `ResponseEntity`

Comment: You can copy string from response and pass it to `Main` for test. And what is `um`? PS: I found it is `implicit um: FromRequestUnmarshaller[T]`

Comment: I *can* convert `List[GHRepo]` with use different packages for case classes. I use `"""[{"owner":{"login": "sd"}}]""".parseJson.convertTo[List[GHRepo]]` and got `List(GHRepo(GHUser(sd)))` (I remove 2 fields from case classes to simplify).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally was able to solve it reading [spray's docs](https://github.com/spray/spray-json):

Basically, I created a separated file for each case class and one object called `MyJsonProtocol` with the following code:

```
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val users = jsonFormat2(GHUser)
  // ...
}
```

Then in my main app I just import both things:

```
import com.elbauldelprogramador.api.MyJsonProtocol._
import com.elbauldelprogramador.domain.{GHOrg, GHRepo, GHUser}
```